# Some portion of the images downloaded from S3Bucket is appearing black in AWS IOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the following code to download the image from S3Bucket using AWS IOS SDK

```
      let s3BucketName = "mybucket"
        let fileName = "filename.png"

        let downloadFilePath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        let downloadingFileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(downloadFilePath)

        let downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
        downloadRequest.bucket = s3BucketName
        downloadRequest.key  = "\(folder)\(fileName)"
        downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL

         transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWithSuccessBlock({
            (task: BFTask!) -> BFTask! in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                var image = UIImage(named: "\(documentDirectory)/\(fileName)")
                imageView.image = image
                loaderCellView.hidden = true
            })
            return nil
        })
```

[image]
whenever the image is getting downloaded some portion of the image is getting black. But when I look at the image in S3 Bucket then it is properly shown there. this happens sometimes and sometimes not. So I am looking for the solution. See the attached picture. Can anyone help me for this? I will be really greatfull for this.

Comment: Looks like the download is being interrupted. Have you tried inspecting the `BFTask` object inside the block? There is an `error` property that may be non-nil in this case.

Comment: I looked at it. Whatever the code I have written inside the BFTask block and dispatch_async block is getting executed. I have read somewhere that we can use AWSTask instead of BFTask. But for that I think I will need to upgrade the AWS SDK. Is there any way so that we can get it done without upgrading the SDK which will be difficult for me because I will need upgrade it manually and I have used BFTask at so many places as the project is onto its final stage.

Comment: Right but you haven't written any code in the BFTask block to check if there was an error. Look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html

Comment: I tried putting check for error whether the error is nil or not. And it shows error is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. I upgraded my AWS SDK and replaced BFTask with AWSTask. It worked like a charm for me. AWS has introduced new individual framework AWSMobileAnalytics.framework which has introduced AWSTask in place of Bolt's BFTask. So it is no more dependent on Bolt framework to run background process for uploading or downloading files as from now AWS has now independent framework AWSMobileAnalytics.framework  for that. Download latest SDK. Delete all json that were contained in old SDK. Then delete all the framework files of old SDK. Then add all the framework files from "frameworks" folder in the newly downloaded SDK. In the bridging header you just need to change the line "#import < AWSCore/ AWSCore.h>" to "#import < AWSMobileAnalytics/ AWSMobileAnalytics.h>". Hope it will help anyone facing the same problem.